# How to remove Symmetry from Cartesian product via Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have composed a cartesian product (A×A) via Linq and removing the reflexive elements is pretty easy (`a != b`), but I struggle with the symmtric elements. Any suggestions? Thx

```
from var a in Stuff
from var b in Stuff
where a != b
where // Remove symmetric Elements
select new { A = a, B = b}
```

This Query contains the cartesion product over `Stuff` without the reflexive elements ( (a,a), (b,b) and so on). The symmetic elements are still in it ( (a,b) and (b,a) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could index your source enumeration by projecting to an anonymous type that keeps the index of the element and then use the index to remove the symmetrical elements in your cross join:

```
 var IndexedStuff = Stuff.Select((item,index) => new { Item = item, Index = index});
 var result = (from a in IndexedStuff
               from b in IndexedStuff
               where a.Index < b.Index
               select new { A = a.Item, B = b.Item });
```

This has the advantage that it works on any source enumeration, items do not need to be comparable.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative would be to only pick the results with the largest element first.

```
where a > b // Remove symmetric Elements
```

Comment: @MarcelBenthin, is `a.CompareTo(b)` defined?

Comment: But I can probably make up an arbitrary definition for that. Thx

Comment: `a < b` is not the same as *the index* of a <  *the index* of b - this would not work for a non-ordered enumeration, nor for types that are not comparable.

Answer (score 0):

```
from var a in Stuff 
from var b in Stuff 
where a < b 
select new { A = a, B = b}
```